# How to use the default AWS credentials chain for an S3 backed Maven repository in a Gradle build?

Tags: maven, gradle, amazon-s3

According to [Gradle documention](https://docs.gradle.org/2.4/userguide/dependency_management.html) (Example 50.27), we can use S3 backed Maven repositories with Gradle 2.4. However, the only example given in the docs passes explicit AWS credentials to the S3 repository declaration:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "s3://someS3Bucket/maven2"
        credentials(AwsCredentials) {
            accessKey "someKey"
            secretKey "someSecret"
        }
    }
}
```

I need to do the same thing, but I want Gradle to use the DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain, from the AWS JDK, instead of explicit credentials. Something like:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "s3://someS3Bucket/maven2"
        credentials(AwsCredentials) {
            // Default AWS chain here?
        }
    }
}
```

This way, it would find the Instance Profile Credentials that I have configured for my EC2 instances where the Gradle build would be running.

Is there a way to accomplish this? Or, is Gradle only capable of authenticating against S3 with explicit credentials given in the build file?

Comment: [Source](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/6277a4dc70fbeea83c111e75c95ba851d1e56ffc/subprojects/core/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/credentials/AwsCredentials.java) looks like that is all there is support for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

More recent versions of Gradle provide a [built-in way](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/repository_types.html#example_declaring_a_s3_backed_maven_and_ivy_repository_using_iam) to use credentials from the default provider chain, eg:

```
maven {
    url "s3://myCompanyBucket/maven2"
    authentication {
       awsIm(AwsImAuthentication) // load from EC2 role or env var
    }
}
```

This avoids the need to manually create an instance of the provider chain and pass in the credential values.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to accomplish the pom.xml generation, as well as the upload to S3, with the following build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.10.58'
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'com.acme'
            artifactId 'sample-gradle-dependency'
            version '1.0'
            from components.java
        }
    }
    repositories {      
        maven {
            url "s3://my-bucket/releases"
            credentials(AwsCredentials) {
                def defaultCredentials = new com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain().getCredentials()
                accessKey defaultCredentials.getAWSAccessKeyId()
                secretKey defaultCredentials.getAWSSecretKey()
            }
        }       
    }   
}
```

This one requires `apply plugin: maven-publish`, which apparently is the new version of `apply plugin: maven`.

This one runs with:

```
$ gradle publish
```

Comment: Does this read credentials out of `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`?

Answer (score 3):

Untested, but I would try:

```
buildscript { 
    repositories { 
        mavenCentral() 
    } 

    dependencies { 
        classpath 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.10.58' 
    } 
}

import com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain

repositories {
    maven {
        url "s3://someS3Bucket/maven2"
        credentials(AwsCredentials) {

            def defaultCredentials = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain().getCredentials()
            accessKey defaultCredentials.getAWSAccessKeyId()
            secretKey defaultCredentials.getAWSSecretKey()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to add:

`buildscript {
 repositories {
  mavenCentral()
 }
 dependencies {
  classpath 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.10.58'
 }
}`

But in the end, it worked. However, it's not generating a pom.xml.

Comment: pom generation sounds like a different issue, you should raise a new question. Please show your publications section if you're using `maven-publish`

Comment: I think it's also important to point out that the answer above does not require any particular plugin. It's not necessary to `apply plugin: maven` or anything else. It just works.

Comment: And one more thing: When we use 'traditional' repositories such as Archiva or Nexus, they don't let you override the same version with a new upload. However, when we use S3 backed repositories, we can override a version if we upload the artifacts multiple times.