# CodeBuild Unable to obtain AWS Credentials in Gradle Script

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, gradle, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use the maven-publish plugin to upload my artifact to S3 but my script is unable to obtain the AWS Credentials.
Followed this question: [How to use the default AWS credentials chain for an S3 backed Maven repository in a Gradle build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35852475/how-to-use-the-default-aws-credentials-chain-for-an-s3-backed-maven-repository-i)
Also have tried DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain but all have not worked. Basically unable to get the aws credentials in the codebuild script. Any tips would be appreciated.

CodeBuild Logs:

```
02:40:37.373 [DEBUG] [com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client] Region for my-repo is us-east-1
02:40:37.373 [DEBUG] [com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain] Unable to load credentials from EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY))
02:40:37.373 [DEBUG] [com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain] Unable to load credentials from SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from Java system properties (aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey)
02:40:37.373 [DEBUG] [com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain] Unable to load credentials from com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@124705d: profile file cannot be null
02:40:39.376 [DEBUG] [com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain] Unable to load credentials from com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper@74a7b8dc: Unable to load credentials from service endpoint
02:40:39.376 [DEBUG] [com.amazonaws.services.s3.S3CredentialsProviderChain] No credentials available; falling back to anonymous access
02:40:39.376 [DEBUG] [com.amazonaws.request] Sending Request: PUT https://my-repo.s3.amazonaws.com /releases/com/mycompany/common/0.0.1/common-0.0.1.pom Headers: (x-amz-acl: bucket-owner-full-control, User-Agent: aws-sdk-java/1.11.407 Linux/4.14.152-98.182.amzn1.x86_64 OpenJDK_64-Bit_Server_VM/11.0.3+7 java/11.0.3 groovy/2.5.4 kotlin/1.3.20, amz-sdk-invocation-id: 057fae4d-67c5-4256-5804-7b17a09bba76, Content-Length: 2967, Content-Type: application/octet-stream, ) 
02:40:39.376 [DEBUG] [com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain] Unable to load credentials from EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY))
02:40:39.376 [DEBUG] [com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain] Unable to load credentials from SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from Java system properties (aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey)
02:40:39.376 [DEBUG] [com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain] Unable to load credentials from com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@124705d: profile file cannot be null
02:40:41.378 [DEBUG] [com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain] Unable to load credentials from com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper@74a7b8dc: Unable to load credentials from service endpoint
02:40:41.378 [DEBUG] [com.amazonaws.services.s3.S3CredentialsProviderChain] No credentials available; falling back to anonymous access
```

build.gradle

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.*

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.645'
        classpath 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.645'
        classpath 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sts:1.11.645'
    }
}
plugins {
   ...
   id 'maven-publish'
}
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "s3://my-repo/releases"
            authentication {
                awsIm(AwsImAuthentication)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working.
Left the code above the same and modified my buildspec.yml to:

```
      - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(echo $temp_role | jq .Credentials.AccessKeyId)
      - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(echo $temp_role | jq .Credentials.SecretAccessKey)
      - export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$(echo $temp_role | jq .Credentials.SessionToken)
      - docker run -i --rm -w /opt/gradle -v $PWD:/opt/gradle -v $HOME/.gradle:/root/.gradle gradle:5.4-jdk11 ./gradlew publish
```

Update: worked once and now it's not working again. Not sure what's going on here. Still investigating.